# Python outputs a .txt file, which's format differs depending on the text editor I use to open it

Tags: python, text, output

So I have some python code taht outputs some data to a .txt file like this:

```
f3 = codecs.open(r'C:\Users\dimrizo\Desktop\PythonData\GTFS\routes.txt','w+',"UTF-8")

f3.write('route_id,agency_id,route_short_name,route_long_name,route_desc,route_type,route_url,route_color,route_text_color\n')
f3.write('blah,blah,blah,blah,blah,blah,blah,blah,blah\n')
```

Problem is that if I open the produced file with the simple windows text editor the text is not properly formatted. The "\n" don't even count. If I open the file with sublime text everything is fine it is formatted as it should. What should I do in order to see the text properly formatted in both the editors?

Comment: Notepad does not handle `\n` correctly. It has to be `\r\n`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is a problem with notepad itself. It can't handle "Linux newlines" instead it only recognizes "windows newlinew", so you have to write `\r\n` and then you will see the linebreaks in notepad.